# ModalView Nativescript result

Tags: angular, react-native, nativescript

```
modalCrongorama() {
    let options = {
        context: {},
        fullscreen: true,
        viewContainerRef: this.viewRef
    };

    this.modalService.showModal(CronogramaManejoComponent, options)
        .then((result: CronogramaManejo)=>{

            this.idCrongrama = result.id;
            this.nomeCronograma = result.manejos;

            console.log(this.idCrongrama);
            console.log(this.nomeCronograma);

            this.addInsumo(result.id, result.manejos);
        });
}
```

I built a page that when I click opens a ModalView with a list of people and when I select a person and it returns as selected

Error:
if I click a second time to open the modal with list of people it doesn't work - the list doesn't load.

On the log:  The first time passes into the constructor, ngOnInit ....
the second time only passes into constructor, not more on the ngOninit..  why?

Comment: How do you close the modal post selection? Are you able to reproduce the issue with Playground?

Comment: sorted out!!!  
I created a new service to call viewContainerRef.

modalCrongorama() {
        const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
            viewContainerRef: this.uiService.getRootVCRef()
            ?  this.uiService.getRootVCRef()
            : this.vcRef,
            context: {},
            fullscreen: true
        };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted out!!!
I created a new **service** to call **viewContainerRef**.

```
modalCrongorama() {
        const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
            viewContainerRef: this.uiService.getRootVCRef()
            ?  this.uiService.getRootVCRef()
            : this.vcRef,
            context: {},
            fullscreen: true
        };
```